# Prolog difference routine

Tags: prolog, logic

I need some help with a routine that I am trying to create. I need to make a routine that will look something like this:

```
difference([(a,b),(a,c),(b,c),(d,e)],[(a,_)],X).

X = [(b,c),(d,e)].
```

I really need help on this one..

I have written a method so far that can remove the first occurrence that it finds.. however I need it to remove all occurrences. Here is what I have so far...

```
memberOf(A, [A|_]).
memberOf(A, [_|B]) :-
    memberOf(A, B).

mapdiff([], _, []) :- !.
mapdiff([A|C], B, D) :-
        memberOf(A, B), !,
        mapdiff(C, B, D).
mapdiff([A|B], C, [A|D]) :-
        mapdiff(B, C, D).
```

I have taken this code from listing(subtract).

I don't fully understand what it does, however I know it's almost what I want. I didn't use subtract because my final code has to be compatible with WIN-Prolog... I am testing it on SWI Prolog.

Comment: Your code works for me (in SWI-Prolog and GNU-Prolog). I don't know WIN-Prolog, so I cannot help you there.

Comment: Well it works but it doesnt remove all of the occurances of A. It only removes the first.

Comment: You're right. Somehow I looked wrong (?). I think the problem is that the member check performs unification, and as a result after the first test `(a, _)` becomes `(a, b)`, which will no longer match with `(a, c)`. I'm thinking about a nice solution...

Comment: Nope, sorry. I hope some more skilled Prolog user can help you. (I should be spending time writing my thesis :)

Answer (score 4):

Tricky one! *humble coffee* has the right idea. Here's a fancy solution using double negation:

```
difference([], _, []).
difference([E|Es], DL, Res) :-
    \+ \+ member(E, DL), !,
    difference(Es, DL, Res).
difference([E|Es], DL, [E|Res]) :-
    difference(Es, DL, Res).
```

Works on SWI-PROLOG. Explanation:

Clause 1: Base case. Nothing to diff against!

Clause 2: If E is in the difference list DL, the `member/2` subgoal evaluates to `true`, but we don't want to accept the bindings that `member/2` makes between variables present in terms in either list, as we'd like, for example, the variable in the term `(a,_)` to be reusable across other terms, and not bound to the first solution. So, the 1st `\+` removes the variable bindings created by a successful evaluation of `member/2`, and the second `\+` reverses the evaluation state to `true`, as required. The cut occurs after the check, excluding the 3rd clause, and throwing away the unifiable element.

Clause 3: Keep any element not unifiable across both lists.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but something like this could work. You can use `findall` to find all elements which can't be unified with the pattern:

```
?- findall(X, (member(X, [(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)]), X \= (a,_)), Res).
```

gets the reply

```
Res = [ (b, c) ]
```

So

```
removeAll(Pattern, List, Result) :-
  findall(ZZ109, (member(ZZ109, List), ZZ109 \= Pattern), Result).
```

should work, assuming `ZZ109` isn't a variable in `Pattern` (I don't know a way to get a fresh variable for this, unfortunately. There may be a non-portable one in WIN-Prolog). And then `difference` can be defined recursively:

```
difference(List, [], List).
difference(List, [Pattern|Patterns], Result) :- 
  removeAll(Pattern, List, Result1),
  difference(Result1, Patterns, Result).
```

Comment: ZZ109 is a fresh variable. Internally, Prolog changes the name of the variable. It will only be the same variable if you explicitly use ZZ109 within the same clause. That is: the ZZ109 in Pattern might internally be renamed to _123 while ZZ109 in the difference clause will be renamed _314. Nothing to worry about there.. Good solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be easily modified to work by making it so that the `memberOF` predicate just checks to see that there is an element in the list that *can* be unified without actually unifying it. In SWI Prolog this can be done this way:

```
memberOf(A, [B|_]) :- unifiable(A,B,_).
```

But I'm not familiar with WIN-PRolog so don't know whether it has a predicate or operator which only tests whether arguments can be unified.